# Kalman Filter Propagation using two previous time steps

Tags: covariance, kalman-filter

Kalman Filters propagate using a single previous state estimate $\hat{x}$ with covariance $P$. Is there a formal way of propagating using two previous state estimates with different associated covariance matrices $P$?

I'm working on a filter that estimates an attitude vector, however I need to use the previous two state estimates at timestep $k-1$ and $k-2$ for the process model in question. This would imply propagating a mix of the error covariance matrices $P_{k-1|k-1}$ and $P_{k-2|k-2}$ in the standard Riccati propagation equation.

I haven't found any literature detailing a method like this and would be curious if anyone could provide any suggestions!

Comment: Why do you *need* to use the state estimates at timesteps $k-1$ and $k-2$? The Kalman filter is already a minimum variance estimator, so how would your proposed method improve on this?

Comment: Hi: in the same spirit as the comment of mhdadk, the kalman filter ( the observation equation and the system equation ) are markov processes so one only needs the previous estimates. maybe we are not understanding your question ?

Comment: If the process model is linear then you can introduce a dummy state variable to remove dependence on timestep $k-2$.

Comment: I think I'll try @Estacionario 's method of carrying the $k-2$ state in the state and add it into the covariance matrix. My state is an attitude vector embedded in a rotation matrix, for my process model I want be able to calculate the cross product of the previous two attitude vectors to update another part of the state. Hope this makes more sense!